# Creating HTTPS server in iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, https, server, serversocket

My requirement is running a HTTPS server on the device it won't connect to the external clients. Both client and server is my application only.

For example, if there is a request https://myip/getUserData from my app, my app fetch information from core data and returns to the client(that is also my app)

I was able to create an HTTP server in my app following the below link. but I want the same in HTTPS. That means to run the HTTPS server.

> http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html